# Select excluding certain time of the day

Tags: sql, oracle

So I'm trying to query records that don't have a specific timestamp, I don't want to see any records that have a time of 01:00:00 AM

```
select * from records 
  where to_char(record_time,'hh24') not between 1 and 1
```

But I'm still not getting the result set I'm looking for, any help is appreciated.

Comment: *not between 1 and 1* makes no sense. There can never be anything between 1 and 1. They're equal values. Think about it. You want *not equal to*, as in `<> 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT *
  FROM RECORDS
 WHERE NVL(TO_CHAR(record_time,'HH24:MI:SS AM'),'X') <> '01:00:00 AM';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can compare the time with the time truncated back to midnight with one hour added and since `NULL` is never equal to anything you can test for that separately:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   records
WHERE  record_time != TRUNC(record_time) + INTERVAL '1' HOUR
OR     record_time IS NULL;
```